# Pandas Dataframe: Splitting Columns containing lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary, split

We face the challenge that we have a dataframe `patents_original` which **columns consist of lists of dictionaries**. Each dictionary contains reoccurring keys like `'inventor_last_name'`.

```
[{'inventor_last_name': 'Han', 'inventor_first_name': 'Shu-Jen', 'inventor_country': 'US', 'inventor_key_id': '104654'}, {'inventor_last_name': 'Chen', 'inventor_first_name': 'Chia-Yu', 'inventor_country': 'US', 'inventor_key_id': '367934'}]
```

We are seeking columns only containing the items of the recurring keys. So that every `'inventor_last_name'` of a row is listed in a new column called `'inventor_last_name'` (When multiple investors are contained, all of their last names should be listed in one column called 'inventor_last_name'). For the following analysis it is very important that the line affiliation is not changed. The new dataframe should afterwards contain 4 new columns called `'inventor_last_name'`, `'inventor_first_name'`, `'inventor_country'`, and `'inventor_key_id'` (the keys of the prior dictionaries).

Stack overflow provided this code fragment to create a new column and fill it with the items of the key `"inventor_last_name"`:

```
patents_inventors["inventor_last_name"] = [sub_dict["inventor_last_name"] for sub_dict in patents_inventors["inventors"]]
```

The following error occurs:

```
patents_inventors["inventor_last_name"] = [ sub_dict["inventor_last_name"] for sub_dict in patents_inventors["inventors"]]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-46-2c776eb8a76d>", line 1, in <module>
    patents_inventors["inventor_last_name"] = [ sub_dict["inventor_last_name"] for sub_dict in patents_inventors["inventors"]]

  File "<ipython-input-46-2c776eb8a76d>", line 1, in <listcomp>
    patents_inventors["inventor_last_name"] = [ sub_dict["inventor_last_name"] for sub_dict in patents_inventors["inventors"]]

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

For us, as absolute Python amateurs, it seems like Python does not interpret the line as a list of dictionaries. All attempts to transfer the column into the datatype list or dictionary have failed.

**If it helps, I can provide you with the link to the editable excel sheet!**

This is our first post on Stack overflow, so please bear with us if it reads like this. We really appreciate your help!

**Edit:**

The column names are:

```
patent_number
patent_title
patent_abstract
patent_date
patent_num_combined_citations
patent_num_cited_by_us_patents
inventors
assignees
applications
cited_patents
citedby_patents
cpcs
wipos
```

Since I am not quite sure how to shorten the dataframe to post it here, I am linking a picture to the corresponding excel sheet. Hope this helps too.

[exerpt of the corresponding excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPPMD.png)

Comment: It's not clear how the dataframe is actually structured. Please clarify, add a little sample, etc.

Comment: The dataframe itself has the shape `[36015 rows x 14 columns]` and contains patent data mainly in the form of objects. Since the columns are structured in a similar way as the inventors this column is describing for the remaining df. Hope this helps!

Comment: What are the column names? It would be best, if you could create a small articfical sample that replicates the problem. Make it copy-paste-able.

Comment: Hi Timus, I am not familiar with posting df on stack overflow and since the df is that big https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples could not help me that much. I edited the question, hope that helps. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer using apply in these situations because it increases readability. From your question I was not sure if it was a nested list.

**Update:**
The string type means that you first need to parse the object as a dictionary.

```
import json
patents_inventors['parsed_inventors'] = patents_inventors['inventors'].apply(lambda x: [json.loads(y) for y in x])

patents_inventors['inventor_last_name'] = patents_inventors['parsed_inventors'].apply(lambda x: [y['inventor_last_name'] for y in x])
```

Comment: Both code fragments result in the same error.
`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

I guess one of our main problems is, that we are not quite sure about the column's structure. The `.dtypes` reveals that it is an object but since we are quite new to python we are not sure how to handle this information and can't convert it to a different type like a list.

Comment: Check the type of the object because maybe it's a string and you have to parse it first

Comment: This is how the output of the type function looks like.
`[<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>,  ... , <class 'str'>]`

I am not quite sure how to interpret this information. For your information the dataframe was recieved by an api request from patentsview.

Comment: Dear Joeri, the problem has changed another time. The new Error looks as follows
`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict` 
after we have changed the way of JSON decoding from `results = r.json` to `results = json.loads(r.text)`. 
Do you have any clue about how to handle this problem?
Thank you for your help!